# WordPress programmatically change URL and rules

Tags: wordpress

You need to implement:

1. Have link: `site.com/service/window_clean`
2. Need to be: `site.com/london/service/window_clean`

Before `service` need to dynamically substitute the name of the city.

Comment: Will the content be different on each page, or the same?

Comment: Content will match the post window_clean